# How do I "Cancel an event"?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, events

I have two DateTimePickers *dtpDateFrom* and *dtpDateTo*.

I already coded a conditional statement that if dtpDateTo is earlier than dtpDateFrom via their *ValueChanged* event, I would get an error message, but it still **applies the change.**

Example:

1. dtpDateFrom = July 2
2. dtpDateTo = July 3
3. If I change *dtpDateFrom* to July 4 ~> error message + **without performing the July 4 change**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the Validating event for the control. In your code where your validation fails put in e.cancel = true

```
Private Sub dtpDateFrom_Validating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles dtpDateFrom.Validating
    If dtpDateFrom.Value > dtpDateTo.Value Then
        Messagebox.show("From date must be less than To date")
        e.Cancel = True 'Validation failed.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thanks for that. I don't know how I could miss something as simple as e.Cancel in Validating event.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it still applies. What does "VAlueChanged" mean? It means it HAS changed. The event is per documentation hrown POST FACTUM so an exception will not magically roll back time.

The key is to program in such a way that you do the validation and value rejection BEFORE changing the value.

Comment: Ok so how do I detect if it meets the condition, then not perform the change for this simple problem?